# how to switch back to original activity?

Tags: android

I have written a simple app that lists a number of pdf files and when the user clicks on one of them they open up in a pdf viewer (using adobe here).

Heres the code for opening the pdf file :

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(open[filePosition]);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PDF Reader application is not installed in your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Now after viewing the file in the pdf viewer , when the user clicks back it opens up the main menu of the device.

How can i make it go back to my app so the user can open another file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

```
finish();
```

from your code and you should be good.

Comment: Also remove `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: that does it! cant believe i missed that `finish();`
its always the little things :P

Answer (score 0):

Remove finish(), and then it should be :

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(open[filePosition]);
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PDF Reader application is not installed in your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```